# T-SQL stored procedure construction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to develop a T-SQL stored procedure and perform some logic and computation there, but for some reason getting syntax error. I will highlight critical places, where I am not sure how to do it.

```
CREATE PROC AddInvestment
@_Investor nvarchar(89),
@_Sum decimal(19,4),
@_Currency smallint,
@_Rate tinyint,
@_Date date,
@_Comment nvarchar(max)

AS

DECLARE @_MavroRate decimal(19,4)
DECLARE @_Mavro decimal(19,4)

SELECT mr.[40] INTO @_MavroRate <==== ERROR
FROM dbo.MavroRateBuy mr
WHERE mr.Date = @_Date

@_Mavro = _Sum / @_MavroRate <==== ERROR

INSERT INTO Investments(Investor, Sum, Currency, Rate, Date, Mavro, MavroRate, Comment)
VALUES (@_Investor, @_Sum, @_Currency, @_Rate, @_Date, @_Mavro, @_MavroRate, @_Comment)
```

Could you please verify by T-SQL statement and point me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROC AddInvestment
@_Investor nvarchar(89),
@_Sum decimal(19,4),
@_Currency smallint,
@_Rate tinyint,
@_Date date,
@_Comment nvarchar(max)

AS

DECLARE @_MavroRate decimal(19,4)
DECLARE @_Mavro decimal(19,4)

SELECT @_MavroRate = mr.[40]
FROM dbo.MavroRateBuy mr
WHERE mr.Date = @_Date

SET @_Mavro = @_Sum / @_MavroRate

INSERT INTO Investments(Investor, Sum, Currency, Rate, Date, Mavro, MavroRate, Comment)
VALUES (@_Investor, @_Sum, @_Currency, @_Rate, @_Date, @_Mavro, @_MavroRate, @_Comment)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this I suppose:

```
SELECT @_MavroRate = mr.[40]  
FROM dbo.MavroRateBuy mr
WHERE mr.Date = @_Date

SELECT @_Mavro = @_Sum / @_MavroRate
```

@_Sum needs to have a value before it is used.

Comment: To explain why what you did was incorrect - You cannot SELECT INTO a variable. You use SELECT INTO to create a new table.

Answer (score 1):

You missing a `SET` in front of the line `@_Mavro = _Sum / @_MavroRate`.  It should look like the code below.

```
SET @_Mavro = _Sum / @_MavroRate
```

Also, the `INTO` is used to insert your results into a new table, not to set a variable.  The code below will is the correct way to set a variable in a select statement.

```
SELECT @_MavroRate = mr.[40]
FROM dbo.MavroRateBuy mr
WHERE mr.Date = @_Date
```